# Filling in non-rectangles on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a cube made from lines and rectangles on a canvas and I want to fill in areas that aren't rectangles.

Here is my code and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FroggyTGYT/60sqmn95/).

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var height = 250
var width = 250
var edge = {
  x: 8,
  y: 8
}

canvas.height = height
canvas.width = width

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(50, 50, 100, 100)
ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
ctx.stroke()

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(50, 150)
ctx.lineTo(100, 200)
ctx.moveTo(50, 50)
ctx.lineTo(100, 100)
ctx.moveTo(150, 50)
ctx.lineTo(200, 100)
ctx.moveTo(150, 150)
ctx.lineTo(200, 200)
ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray'
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.stroke()
```

```css
canvas {
  background: white;
  /*border-style:solid;*/
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

How would I fill in these areas?[image: these areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to closepath for each side and then call fill:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var height = 250
var width = 250
var edge = {
  x: 8,
  y: 8
}

canvas.height = height
canvas.width = width

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(50, 50, 100, 100)


ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100)

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
ctx.stroke()


ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(50, 150)
ctx.lineTo(100, 200)
ctx.lineTo(100, 100)
ctx.lineTo(50, 50)
ctx.lineTo(50, 150)

//the path is closed now, the fill would color the area 

ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.stroke()

ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill(); 

ctx.moveTo(50, 50)
ctx.lineTo(100, 100)
ctx.moveTo(150, 50)
ctx.lineTo(200, 100)
ctx.moveTo(150, 150)
ctx.lineTo(200, 200)
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.stroke()
```

```css
canvas {
  background: white;
  /*border-style:solid;*/
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```